How to restore minimized Window on Mac?
Sometimes I somehow manage to make a window very small on my Mac: see the grey area in the attached screenshot, How can I restore the window?
The window still seems to be operational, but just very small and I cannot move it while dragging and found no way to restore it.
Mission control shows the window, but when I select it it will be small again.


Try holding the Option key and hover over where the green Full Screen button is approximately, until you get the resizing options menu. There are some more options you could try out from this How-To Geek article.
